# How can I dynamically advance Rokbox slide?

Tags: mobile, joomla, mootools

we have a site using Joomla, and the rockbox plugin for a javascript-based slideshow. I want to make it work with swipe on mobile devices and have found a mootools library which will pair well, but I can't seem to find the name of the function I need to call to dynamically move the slideshow forward. Anyone know?

Comment: post some code / links / urls? jsfiddle? version of mootools? as it stands, i am inclined to vote to close the question as it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the eval "encrypted" rokbox 2.5 code base beautified by http://jsbeautifier.org/

However as Dimitar pointed out I had to make many assumptions I used the latest version from:
http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-downloads/club/1005-rokbox

If this is not your version, take the JS from your version and beautify it you will than see the methods available to you and you can simply extend the class as needed using mootools core found here:

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class

Link to beautified code base:
http://jsfiddle.net/sFDSa/

Hope this helps you solve your problem,
Tim

Comment: wow. award for the longest constructor function in a mootools class.